# Sum a single column of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

I'd like to make a sum of all [Suggested] field values.

```
[
    [
        'Id' => 4,
        'Suggested' => 1322,
        'proximite_r' => 30924.8470655462,
    ],
    [
        'Id' => 7,
        'Suggested' => 773,
        'proximite_r' => 32229.1036975145,
    ],
]
```

The total should be: `2095`

Comment: Can you reformat your array to be more readable please?

Comment: I don't think your outermost structure is clear.  You have multiple arrays at "root" level.  Is this an array of arrays?

Comment: Look for a function called `array_column` and then there is [`array_sum`](http://php.net/array_sum);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$Sum = 0;
foreach ($row as $item) {
   $Sum += $item['Suggested']; // or else index
}
echo $Sum;
```

Answer (score 8):

Here you go, buddie: [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) like a boss

```
// PHP >= 5.3
$sum = array_reduce($items, function($sum, $item){
  return $sum += $item['Suggested'];
}, 0);
```

---

```
// PHP 5.2
function _sum($sum, $item){
  return $sum += $item['Suggested'];
}
$sum = array_reduce($items, '_sum', 0);
```

Sadly PHP <= 5.2 does not support closures, so you have to define the function separately.

Comment: @FrancoisM, you're probably running PHP < 5.3 then. I'll make a note.

Comment: @FrancoisM, I added a PHP <= 5.2 solution as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
$sum = array_sum(
              array_map(function($item) { return $item["Suggested"]; }, $items)
       );
```

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt What's the overkill about it?

Comment: Overkill agreed; requires iterating through the collection twice. A simple `array_reduce()` as described in my answer will suffice.

Comment: Faster, maybe, but this code is in isolation. Inside of a web application, it's hardly going to be a bottleneck, especially with any  disk usage or database access.

Answer (score 0):

Given the [`array_column`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/array_column) function that will probably arrive in PHP 5.5 :

```
function array_column($input, $key) {
    if (is_array($key) || !is_array($input)) return array();
    $array = array();
    foreach($input as $v) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $v)) $array[]=$v[$key];
    }
    return $array;
}
```

(source: php.net)

You could use this :

```
$sum = array_sum(array_column($items, 'Suggested'));
```

Of course, this is major overkill and I only wanted to point out that this is also a way to achieve it.

Comment: @webnoob It's overkill, yes. However, it's a way to achieve it and that's why I point it out.

Comment: I don't think this is overkill at all.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to iterate through the array is using for loop, Suppose it is $arr:

```
<?php    
function getSumOfKey($arr, $key){
     $sum = 0;
     for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
      (is_numeric($arr[$i][$key]))? $sum += $arr[$i][$key] : continue;
     }
     return $sum;
    } 
?>
```

To implement it:

```
echo 'The sum is: '.getSumOfKey($arr, 'Suggested');
```